# Visual Studio Code Jupyter Notebook How to remove the "Select Cell Language Mode" rendered on each cell

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

If I know all my notebooks are 100% python, I would rather not see the button (with no boundary) with "Python" on every cell. These are needed only if you want to switch language. In my case, I would rather have a less cluttered env.

[image]

Comment: You can start a discussion in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/discussions) and ask for votes to get support, so that developers can adjust it. However, I think the button itself is very convenient and will not affect the use.

Comment: I did search the doc, but post here just wondering... but it does seem not supported. I will mostly start this on github. This is not great UX. "Do not repeat yourself" is a good guide for good programming and UX.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are requesting is not a supported functionality. Jupyter notebooks are meant to mix programming code and markdown, so if you turn out to want to add or change to a markdown cell but the type will be hidden, how would you do this? It's quite convenient and the little text doesn't trouble you in any way.

Comment: IMHO, that button is not great UX. It is making assumption that ppl mix at every cell. I am comparing with most other impl. of jupyter out there, none have clutters like this, and it is very distracting. The motto I used "don't repeat yourself" for programming as well as UI.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178952